# Makefile:44: recipe for target 'get_mvcmd' failed make: *** [get_mvcmd] Error 1

Tags: intel, fpga, yolo, zynq, ncsdk

I'm following this http://www.fpgadeveloper.com/2018/04/setting-up-the-pynq-z1-for-the-intel-movidius-neural-compute-stick.html to run yolov3 on Xilinx Pynq-Z1.

I am getting an error while running the make command in the /ncsdk/api/src folder. 
[Error_Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqE94.png)

Can some help me solve this? Or has anyone been able to run YOLOv3 on Pynq-z1 board? or a Zybo Board?

TIA.

Comment: In the ncsdk/api/src/getmvcmd.sh there's an if statement on lines 61 thru 72 where the  "Error downloading .  Will try to restore...." comes from. The period by itself indicates `$ncsdk_download_link` isn't set. The second "Error restoring old firmware - directory ./mvnc.old" is from function restore_old_fw() and is a consequence  of the first download fnever having succeeded.  The downloaded https://downloadmirror.intel.com/28192/eng/NCSDK-1.12.01.01.tar.gz contains your firmwared ncsdk-armv7l (inncsdk-armv7l/fw/MvNCAPI.mvcmd.  Explore why getmvcmd fails.

Comment: Pictures of error messages are tiresome to reproduce text from.

Comment: Thanks @user1155120 The issue was in installing downloadmirror.intel.com/28192/eng/NCSDK-1.12.01.01.tar.gz . For some reason wget was failing. I believe this issue is network related and I had to use --no-check-certificate to get the tar file to download and install.

Comment: @user1155120 The installation has been done properly but while trying to run the example codes- hello_ncs_py I get the error saying No NCS Devices found
Any thoughts on that?